# Azure account was suspended, can't unsuspend

Tags: azure

My azure account was suspended because I hit my monthly quota. Fast forward to today which is the next billing month. If I go to my account I can see that it is marked as Active, billing starts today, and my new quota is there.

In the Azure Portal though, it says my account is still suspended so I can't start, for instance, one of the VMs I had created.

How do I open up all my Azure instances again?

Answer (score 0):

Phone customer support.

Or better yet - start a chat - they're much quicker than phoning (and cheaper too).

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/options/

Answer (score 0):

You need create a Billing Ticket.

Login on Windows Azure Portal and follow this sequence:
Upper Right Corner click on your WLiveID>> Contact Microsoft Support>>Support Type: Billing>>Create Ticket>>[Follow the instructions]

[image]